# Group if only specific condition fulfil in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, group-by, aggregation-framework

I want to group some specific records by their `pid` (only groups) if the number of group events are more than 3.

**Example:**

Here the number of events for `group (pid: 200)` is 4 and must be grouped.

```js
- Events -
----------
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'private', pid: 140, data: {...}},
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'group', pid: 800, data: {...}}, // << group 800
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'group', pid: 200, data: {...}}, // << group 200
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'group', pid: 200, data: {...}}, // << group 200
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'private', pid: 140, data: {...}},
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'group', pid: 200, data: {...}}, // << group 200
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'group', pid: 200, data: {...}}, // << group 200
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'private', pid: 130, data: {...}},
```

Here the `group (pid: 200)` is grouped and `is_too_long: true` is added to the record. And `group (pid: 800)` is not grouped as expected.

```
- Results -
-----------
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'private', pid: 140, data: {...}},
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'group', pid: 800, data: {...}, is_too_long: false}, // << group 800
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'private', pid: 140, data: {...}},
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'group', pid: 200, is_too_long: true}}, // << group 200 (with [is_too_long: true])
{_id: ObjectId, type: 'private', pid: 130, data: {...}, is_too_long: false},
```

I tried some other queries but none worked! Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$facet` to separate `private` and `group` documents,
- `$group` by `pid` and group document in a array
- `$cond` check condition if grouped documents are greater than or equal to 3 then slice single element from array and set `is_too_long: true` otherwise false
- `$map` to iterate loop of `docs` array and put boolean property `is_too_long`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `root` array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `root` object to root
- `$concatArrays`, concat `private` and `group` array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `root` array
- `$replaceRoot` to replace `root` object in root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      private: [{ $match: { type: "private" } }],
      group: [
        { $match: { type: "group" } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$pid",
            root: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            root: {
              $cond: [
                { $gte: [{ $size: "$root" }, 3] },
                {
                  is_too_long: true,
                  docs: { $slice: ["$root", 1] }
                },
                {
                  is_too_long: false,
                  docs: "$root"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            root: {
              $map: {
                input: "$root.docs",
                in: { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { is_too_long: "$root.is_too_long" }] }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$root" },
        { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$root" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $project: { root: { $concatArrays: ["$private", "$group"] } } },
  { $unwind: "$root" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$root" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DYU014JB35G)